# Advanced Searching and Filtering On Excel with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have managed to make a code which searches through out all tabs within a Excel database using visual basic. However, the search only will tell me where the information is located and will not display the information.

The following code is below:

```
Sub SearchWordInEntireWorkbook()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim strWhat As String
Dim cell As Range
Dim Found As Boolean
strWhat = Application.InputBox("What word do you want to search in this workbook?", "Search Word!", Type:=2)
If strWhat = "" Then
   MsgBox "No search word entered.", vbExclamation, "Search Cancelled!"
   Exit Sub
End If

For Each ws In Worksheets
   With ws.Cells
      Set cell = .Find(what:=strWhat, lookat:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False)
      If Not cell Is Nothing Then
         Found = True
         MsgBox "The Word " & strWhat & " is found in " & cell.Address(0, 0) & " on " & ws.Name & " sheet."
      End If
   End With
Next ws
If Not Found Then
   MsgBox "The word " & strWhat & " is not found on any sheet in this workbook.", vbExclamation, "Word Not Found!"
End If
End Sub
```

What I need is the data to be displayed when you run the search instead of telling me where the data is located.

Please can anyone help me out with this? If you need any additional information let me know. 
I understand that there

Comment: instead of "Found=True", put this code--> "cell.Select

Comment: Just done that and it is not working :(

Comment: before that, put this code as well, coz i missed the point that the cell might be in another sheet-->Sheets(cell.Parent.Name).Select, or in a one-liner-->Application.Goto Sheets(cell.Parent.Name).range(cell.Address)

Comment: You could add in another sheet at the start and enable hyperlinks to each Number. However, what I need is once the data is found it will filter the sheets.

Comment: what do you mean by filtering the sheet? i put the whole code as an answer, can you check that again please

Comment: Currently It tells me where the data is the code above. I need it to Filter the tables its found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as continuation of my comment

```
    Sub SearchWordInEntireWorkbook()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim strWhat As String
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim Found As Boolean
    strWhat = Application.InputBox("What word do you want to search in this workbook?", "Search Word!", Type:=2)
    If strWhat = "" Then
       MsgBox "No search word entered.", vbExclamation, "Search Cancelled!"
       Exit Sub
    End If

    For Each ws In Worksheets
       With ws.Cells
          Set cell = .Find(what:=strWhat, lookat:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False)
          If Not cell Is Nothing Then
             Found = True
             'MsgBox "The Word " & strWhat & " is found in " & cell.Address(0, 0) & " on " & ws.Name & " sheet."
             Application.Goto Sheets(cell.Parent.Name).range(cell.Address)
'edit starts
         ans = MsgBox("is this the one you r looking for. if so, say yes and quit, else say no and go to the next result", vbYesNo)
         If ans = vbYes Then
            Exit For
         End If
'edit ends
          End If
       End With
    Next ws
    If Not Found Then
       MsgBox "The word " & strWhat & " is not found on any sheet in this workbook.", vbExclamation, "Word Not Found!"
    End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: This actually works. However, there needs to be a delay in between to allow yourself to stay on these pages. We're getting closer. We could filter out the data if that is possible

Comment: why delay?can you be more precise about your request?

Comment: how about this: after my added code, add this one too. ActiveCell.CurrentRegion.AutoFilter Field:=activecell.column, Criteria1:=activecell.value

Comment: Hi, Once the object is found. It then goes ahead and find the next object automatically. For example; if there are two results called "AMAR02" the first result will be displayed on table 1 and then it will go to the next table where it finds "AMAR02". I was wondering if adding some sort of delay or word to go to the next result? Instead of automatically changing.

Comment: ah i see now. why don't you use Find tool of Excel. Click options, and then select "Workbook" in Within option, and finally click Find All? is there a special need for VBA?

Comment: Reason for this because, the data needs to be filtered out by table. Here is an example; "AMAR02" table  "AMAR01" table  "AMAR03" table  "AMAR06" table  Have the word bedfordshire in.  Now "AMAR09" table  "AMAR04" table  "AMAR02" table  "AMAR07" table  have the name Midlands in. So what this code needs to do is filter the tables out. Hope this makes sense now

Answer (score 0):

Currently you report the address with

```
 MsgBox "The Word " & strWhat & " is found in " & cell.Address(0, 0) & " on " & ws.Name & " sheet."
```

If you want to add the value stored in the cell, just add something to report the value:

```
MsgBox "The Word " & strWhat & " is found in " & cell.Address(0, 0) & " on " & ws.Name & " sheet. The cell contains:" & Cell.Value
```

Comment: The data isn't displaying it is just telling me directly where the word is located on the Sheets. I just need the search to then filter the information to show the data.

Comment: You replaced your msgbox line with the one I suggested? This should tell you: `"The Word XYZ is found in $A$14 on TABNAME sheet. The cell contains: 123XYZab"`